# Is there a way to write the text in a list in bold automatically?

Tags: enumerate, bold

Is there a way to write lists with `enumerate` in bold automatically? I'd be glad to just write `\item text` instead of `\item \textbf{text}` all the time.

Comment: Like that? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[before=\bfseries, font=\normalfont]
\item text
\item text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}`

Comment: Should the numbers be in bold as well, or just the text?

Comment: Perhaps `\textbf{\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}}`